# How to run r code within the latex code in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, inline-code

Consider the following code in `Rmarkdown`, which produces a graph as below:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\captionsetup{skip=0pt}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{A test caption}
\end{figure}
```

Output:

[image]

Now, instead of just using a graph, I would like to create my own plot in `Rmarkdown`, for example, using this code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\captionsetup{skip=0pt}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{plot(mtcars$mpg)}
\caption{A test caption}
\end{figure}
```

but the following error is produced instead:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `plot(mtcars$mpg)' not found.
```

Is there any way to run r codes within latex?

Answer (score 2):

R Markdown doesn't work this way. If you are using RStudio, it is pretty easy. In the R Markdown file, type

```
plot(mtcars$mpg)
```

In other words, you need to start your code with three back-ticks and {r}, and stop your code with three back-ticks again. Your R code written this way will produce the plot you require. After that, click on "knit" button, or use rmarkdown::render(your_file_name).

What you have written in the question means you have produced this chart, and saved that chart as a file in your working directory. If you have saved your plot in the working directory, your code will still work. Try it.

Comment: I need the "\captionsetup{skip=0pt}" to reduce the distance between figure and caption, which I couldn't figure out how to do it in markdown, but in latex can be done using the  "\captionsetup{skip=0pt}"

Comment: Then there are other ways to do it. The first way is to save the raw LaTeX file. In the R Markdown YAML, put "keep_tex: true". That way, R Markdown will save the raw LaTeX file also. Open it, and add this line "\captionsetup{skip=0pt}" at appropriate place. The second way is to save your plot as a jpeg or PNG file first. And instead of writing "\includegraphics[width=6cm]{plot(mtcars$mpg)}", write \includegraphics[width=6cm]{your_file_name.jpeg or your_file_name.PNG)}. The third way is to create a .cls file (a LaTeX class file) in which distance between figure and caption is reduced already.

Answer (score 2):

you could try plotting to a file device in an R code chunk *e.g*.

```
png(filename="mtcars_mpg.png")
plot(mtcars$mpg)
dev.off()
```

You can hide this chunk by using `include = FALSE` in the chunk options.

Then just bring the file in with your LaTeX code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\captionsetup{skip=0pt}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{mtcars_mpg.png}
\caption{A test caption}
\end{figure}
```